# Why are sorted python lists treated as equivalent when they are not?

Tags: python, list

In something I am working on a wordle solver that checks anagrams. The function below is just trying to identify if two word are anagrams, but it always returns true. (I know this is probably not the best way to do it, but I want to avoid this bug in future code.)

```py
def isAnagram(word1: str, word2: str) -> bool:
word1List = []
word2List = []

    for letter in word1:
        word1List.append(letter)
    for letter in word2:
        word2List.append(letter)
    
    word1List.sort()
    word2List.sort()
    
    return word1List.sort() == word2List.sort() # This always returns true
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be because `list.sort()` sorts the list *in place*, i.e. it does not return anything, hence your final comparison basically comparing `None` with `None` (which is always `True`)

You should just change your code to:

```
def isAnagram(word1: str, word2: str) -> bool:
    word1List = []
    word2List = []

    for letter in word1:
        word1List.append(letter)
    for letter in word2:
        word2List.append(letter)
    
    word1List.sort()
    word2List.sort()
    
    return word1List == word2List
```